# How to convert a group of two objects to a single path in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg, path

I'm trying to convert a group of two objects in Inkscape to a (single) combined path. When I select the image with the arrow tool, it says the following:

[image]

I tried converting it to a single path by means of the Path -> Object to Path option, but then it says “No objects to convert to path in selection”.

I'm not quite sure what to do next. How can I convert this group of two objects to a single path?

Comment: Ungroup the paths. Combine doesn't work on a group. Or alternatively, double click the group to enter it, and select both paths, then combine. Double click somewhere blank to exit the group.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes, thank you, I've now done this. I'm now trying to apply the outset tool on it, without much success.

Comment: outset doesn't work on strokes, it only affects paths.

Comment: @BillyKerr Maybe post that comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Ungroup the paths. Combine doesn't work on a group. Or alternatively, double click the group to enter it, and select both paths, then combine. Double click somewhere blank to exit the group.

(copy of Billy Kerr comment)